# Swift + Realm: How to change an outer variable from inside a collection.find's scope

Tags: swift, mongodb, scope, realm

Following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/mongodb-remote-access/) tutorial, I've written the following class:

```
import RealmSwift
import Darwin
import SwiftUI

let app = App(id: "my-app-id")

class AccessManager: Object {
    @objc dynamic var isInTime: Bool = false
    
    func foo2() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func foo1() {
        app.login(credentials: Credentials.anonymous) { (result) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Login failed: \(error)")
                case .success(let user):
                    print("Login as \(user) succeeded!")
                    
                    let client = app.currentUser!.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")
                    let database = client.database(named: "my-database")
                    let collection = database.collection(withName: "my-collection")
                    let identity = "my-identity"
    
                    collection.find(filter: ["_partition": AnyBSON(identity)], { (result) in
                        switch result {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Call to MongoDB failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        case .success(let documents):
                            self.bar = self.foo2()
                            print(self.bar) // prints true
                        }
                    })
                    print(self.bar) // prints false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I change the value of `self.bar` inside of `collection.find`'s scope (using the `self.foo2` function), its value doesn't change outside of that scope - i.e in the first `print(self.bar)` - `true` is being printed, but in the second one - `false` is printed.

How can I change `self.bar`'s value so the change will also take effect outside of `collection.find`'s scope?

Comment: For clarity, you are not using the Realm SDK, you're bypassing that and talking directly to the server with MongoClient and the Query API. You may want to consider the SDK as it simplifies interacting with the back end MongoDB Server. If the goal of your code is to update a value, you would likely need to call `collection.updateOneDocument()` which can be found in the [UpdateDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/mongodb-remote-access/#update-documents) section. Also, be careful with closures as the code following the closure will execute *before* the code in the closure.

Comment: @Jay I'm trying to update the value of the variable self.bar according to the result of foo2. However, I am unable to update it in a way that will take effect outside of collectiom.find's scope.
self.bar is not a property of a document.

Comment: Right. So closures are asynchronous and the code following the closure will (may) execute before the code in the closure. So that code will print false before the value is set to true. Code is faster than the internet so data is only valid *in the closure*.

Comment: @Jay Thanks! That appears to be the issue - after placing sleep(2) before the code that follows the closure - the variable does update. How do you suggest I can solve this without using sleep?

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer without understanding what you're trying to do. What's the purpose of setting self.bar to something? What's the next step in the sequence? Whatever it is, it should be called from within the closure. In other words; suppose you are downloading data to be displayed in a tableView. You get call the function to get the data from MongoDB (the collection) and then within the closure following the call, you would populate your dataSource *and* call tableView.reload to update the UI.

Comment: @Jay I understand, seems that I need to do some refactoring. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jay commented:

> closures are asynchronous and the code following the closure will
> (may) execute before the code in the closure. So that code will print
> false before the value is set to true. Code is faster than the
> internet so data is only valid in the closure.

This is why in my case, the `print(self.bar)` outside of the closure was executed before the `collection.find` closure. Therefore it's result was `false` instead of `true`.